# ReactJS + AWS Amplify: MUI Select, getting `MenuItem` must be used within `Menu`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After copy/pasting the JSX from https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/
into an existing component, I was getting `Uncaught Error: MenuItem must be used within Menu`
This was maddening, but I figured out why it was happening, so wanted to share.

Answer (score 0):

I had the import of MenuItem from AWS Amplify instead of mui. There is an Amplify MenuItem component, which is of course not compatible with MUI Select.

Replace
import { MenuItem } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

import {  MenuItem } from "@mui/material";